# Error while validating the service descriptor using Asp .NET core

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, jwt

I am trying to create a logout mechanism in logout action method in Accounts Controller. For that, I need to deactivate my JWT token. I followed this tutorial to deactivate JWT token. My project is showing error when I run the project after applying this code in my project.

[Canceling JWT tokens in .NET Core](https://piotrgankiewicz.com/2018/04/25/canceling-jwt-tokens-in-net-core/)

My code is as follows.

**Startup.cs**

```
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // New
            services.AddTransient<TokenManagerMiddleware>();
            services.AddTransient<ITokenManager, TokenManager>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            var authPol = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                         .AddAuthenticationSchemes(
                                                         new string[] { 
           JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme })
                                         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                         .Build();
                      
            services.AddControllers(
            config => 
            {
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authPol));
            }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
            .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();

        services.AddDbContext<BikeStoresContext>();

        // JWT Token code is there below this...
        }


      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "BikeStoreAPI v1"));
            }

            app.UseMiddleware<TokenManagerMiddleware>();

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();


            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

**TokenManagerMiddleware.cs**

```
public class TokenManagerMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly ITokenManager _tokenManager;

    public TokenManagerMiddleware(ITokenManager tokenManager)
    {
        _tokenManager = tokenManager;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        if (await _tokenManager.IsCurrentActiveToken())
        {
            await next(context);
            return;
        }
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    }
    
}
```

**ITokenManager.cs**

```
public interface ITokenManager
{
    Task<bool> IsCurrentActiveToken();

    Task DeactivateCurrentAsync();

    Task<bool> IsActiveAsync(string token);

    Task DeactivateAsync(string token);

    Task SetToken(string token);
}
```

**TokenManager.cs**

```
public class TokenManager : ITokenManager
{
    private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;


    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public TokenManager(IDistributedCache cache, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task SetToken(string token)
    {
        await _cache.SetStringAsync(token, token);
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsCurrentActiveToken()
     => await IsActiveAsync(GetCurrentAsync());

    public async Task DeactivateCurrentAsync()
        => await DeactivateAsync(GetCurrentAsync());


    public async Task<bool> IsActiveAsync(string token)
        => await _cache.GetStringAsync(GetKey(token)) == null;

    public async Task DeactivateAsync(string token)
        => await _cache.SetStringAsync(GetKey(token),
            " ", new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
            {
                AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow =
                    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720)
            });

    private string GetCurrentAsync()
    {
        var authorizationHeader = _httpContextAccessor
            .HttpContext.Request.Headers["authorization"];

        return authorizationHeader == StringValues.Empty
            ? string.Empty
            : authorizationHeader.Single().Split(" ").Last();
    }

    private static string GetKey(string token)
    => $"tokens:{token}:deactivated";

}
```

**AccountsController.cs**

```
UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager;
RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

private readonly ITokenManager tokenManager;

public AccountsController(UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager, 
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager, ITokenManager _tokenManager)
{
    userManager = _userManager;
    signInManager = _signInManager;
    roleManager = _roleManager;

    tokenManager = _tokenManager;
}

[HttpPost("logout")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await tokenManager.DeactivateCurrentAsync();
    return NoContent();
}
```

When I tried to run the project, I am getting this error:

> System.AggregateException   HResult=0x80131500   Message=Some services
> are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service
> descriptor 'ServiceType:
> BikeStoreAPI.Middleware.TokenManagerMiddleware Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: BikeStoreAPI.Middleware.TokenManagerMiddleware':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache' while
> attempting to activate
> 'BikeStoreAPI.Services.TokenManagerService.TokenManager'.) (Error
> while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> BikeStoreAPI.Services.TokenManagerService.ITokenManager Lifetime:
> Transient ImplementationType:
> BikeStoreAPI.Services.TokenManagerService.TokenManager': Unable to
> resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache' while
> attempting to activate
> 'BikeStoreAPI.Services.TokenManagerService.TokenManager'.)
> Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection   StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, IServiceProviderEngine engine, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object
> containerBuilder)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()    at
> BikeStoreAPI.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Users\Abhishek\source\repos\BikeStore\BikeStoreAPI\Program.cs:line
> 16
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
>
> Inner Exception 1: InvalidOperationException: Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> BikeStoreAPI.Middleware.TokenManagerMiddleware Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: BikeStoreAPI.Middleware.TokenManagerMiddleware':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache' while
> attempting to activate
> 'BikeStoreAPI.Services.TokenManagerService.TokenManager'.
>
> Inner Exception 2: InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve
> service for type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache' while
> attempting to activate
> 'BikeStoreAPI.Services.TokenManagerService.TokenManager'.

I went through each step and code multiple times but I don't know what went wrong. Can you please help me.

**Edit**
I added below given code in startup.cs but getting this error when Login API is called to generate JWT token.

```
  services.AddDistributedRedisCache(r => { r.Configuration = Configuration["redis:connectionString"]; });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read the exception message carefully.

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache' while attempting to activate 'BikeStoreAPI.Services.TokenManagerService.TokenManager

It says that you didn't register the service for `IDistributedCache` while `TokenManager` attempts to get the service.

You need to register the service for [`IDistributedCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0#distributed-memory-cache-1) depending on the distributed cache provider that you want to use.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<TokenManagerMiddleware>();
    services.AddTransient<ITokenManager, TokenManager>();
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    // Register IDistributedCache service
    services.AddDistributedRedisCache(r => { r.Configuration = Configuration["redis:connectionString"]; 

    ...

}
```

Comment: I tried it but getting error when login API is called. I am attaching the error that I am getting in the edit part of question.

Comment: It looks like it is unable to connect the Redis Did you he the Redis connection string is correct? The Redis server is able to be connected?

Comment: But I am not using Redis server......Visual Studop's Kestrel server is used in my project

Comment: Then no point for you to register the Redis service provider. I would suggest reading the link that I shared in the answer to pick the distributed cache service provider and follow the instruction on how to use the cache.

Comment: Can you suggest me what  should I use instead of the above code that you mentioned. Can you please rewrite your answer accordingly.